# Getting Literal Value from a Masked Text Box Input

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, maskedtextbox, radmaskedtextbox

I've set up a Telerik RadMaskedTextBox with a Mask of "####-####". The problem is, when I later grab the value from this box it returns as "########". I'm unfamiliar with MaskedTextBoxes but I'm guessing that this is the default way it's supposed to return my value.

How can I set the "-" as a literal character in the RadMaskedTextBox so it returns the whole value?

ex. "1234-5678" instead of "12345678"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TextWithLiterals` instead of `Text` property.

Comment: This worked. I was initially setting TextWithLiterals as true on the control, this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with the Telerik controls, but you know the mask and you know the value you're getting, so you can construct the formatted value yourself:

```
var val = control.Text;
var mask = control.Mask;
var v = 0;
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var c in mask)
   builder.Append(c == '#' ? val[v++] : c);

return builder.ToString();
```