# RadDateTimePicker + Mask for Data Entry

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, xaml, telerik

**Requirement:** Allow user to enter date in the format of ###### while also have the ability to choose it from a DatePicker (assuming all years entered will be Post 2000.) So for example, user enters 050513 it becomes 5/5/2013. Or if they choose it from the DatePicker, provide the same display. They also want it to select all when the control receives focus so they can easily overwrite any pre-existing date.

**What I tried:** My xaml is much stronger than my c# so I tried to get creative and got really darn close but no cigar, so hoping someone could fill in the blanks but here's where I got. I figured I could leverage what I know about [RadMaskedTextBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/working_with_radmaskedtextbox.html) and [RadDateTimePicker](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddatetimepicker-overview.html) so I intertwined their properties a bit (with the idea I could just use the Box for entry, and the picker for just the icon) but for testing purposes it was something like this;

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox x:Name="radMTB"
             Value="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, 
                     ElementName=radDP}" 
             MaskType="DateTime"
             Mask="d" SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll" />                
    <telerik:RadDateTimePicker x:Name="radDP" 
             InputMode="DatePicker" 
             SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=radMTB}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This works great except for the fact that it still requires them to type the whole date with slashes. So I changed the MaskType to Standard with a Mask="##/##/\2\0##" to insert the "20" so they could enter like 121212 and it become 12/12/2012 right? Thought I had it until I tried to pass the value off to the DatePicker. I Bound the SelectedDate on the Picker to [TextWithLiterals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945986/getting-literal-value-from-a-masked-text-box-input) to get the display value, no luck. Tried Display.Text, Display.Value, just Text, just Value. It wouldn't work with any of them to bind too and pass off to the DatePicker to work...

So I guess my question is, can I still bind to that literal display somehow and make this work using only xaml? Or is [ParseDateTimeValue](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddatetimepicker-how-to-implement-custom-parsing.html) code inevitably required for the [RadDateTimePicker](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddatetimepicker-overview.html)? If so, could someone please share some knowledge and help a guy out with it? Or is there another way all together to fulfill the sought after requirements? This cant be the first time this has come up?

Thanks for reading either way and cheers!

Comment: To the down-voter, at least give an explanation otherwise your opinion helps nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using RadMaskedTextBox, trying using Telerik's RadMaskedDateTimeInput. It is quite a bit more flexible with DateTime values.

```
<telerik:RadMaskedDateTimeInput x:Name="radMTB1"
                                IsClearButtonVisible="False"
                                FormatString="{}{0:M/d/yyyy}"
                                Mask="MMddyy"
                                SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll"
                                Value="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=radDP2}" />
```

More info: http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radmaskedinput-features-controls-datetime.html

Comment: Ha! I saw that same control while digging through their docs trying to make my all xaml solution work and was just waiting to get in and tinker with it. I'll give it a test and we'll see what we can do but if it works I'll be a happy camper! :)

Comment: So I tried that, but replaced the format with "{}{0:M/d/yy}" instead, and removed the mask entirely. This works excellent for everything except they still have to type the whole year out instead of the last two digits. However it did solve the requirement of typing not typing slashes. So definitely +1! Now if I can just figure out how to type in like 101012 to become 10/10/2012 and carry between both controls to reflect as such I'd be set :D

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, the Mask in the above answer does allow the user to only have to type the 2-digit year. After it's entered, the string will be formatted into what is in the FormatString property.

Comment: Tested in SL, didn't work that way. There's nothing to insert the "20" to complete the year. I can tinker again in just a bit though.

Comment: Finally got it figured out, just needed to stringformat in the missing pieces and was able to make it work, cheers